# Allocate memory to variable of type int *a[13][13]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I came across an old code where I need to allocate memory for an array of matrices. Currently it is done by creating a structure matrix and allocating memory by making an arrray of structures.

Like so.

```
struct matrix
{
    int x[13][13];
};
int main()
{
    matrix *push = (matrix*)malloc(sizeof(matrix) * 1000);
    //do stuff
    free(push);
    return 0;
}
```

But now the question.. Do I really need to do this? I know I am allowed to declare a variable of type `int *matrix[13][13];`

But I cant seem to figure out a way to allocate memory to this variable.

I tried `matrix = (int***)malloc(sizeof(int[13][13])*1000);` which results in 
`E0137  expression must be a modifiable lvalue` and honestly in doesnt seem correct either

I know there are many better and creative ways of allocating an array like this, but I am curious

**Questions**

1. `int *matrix[13][13]` what will this kind of variable even mean or represent? Is it a pointer to a 2D matrix or s it an pointer to an array of 2D matrices?
2. How will I use the above mentioned variable?
3. How will I allocate memory for the above variable without using any more variables?

**Clarifications**
From comments it seems `int *matrix[13][13]` represents a matrix of 13x13 int*

What I am asking is actually, is there a way to have a variable with a dynamically allocated first dimension and static 2nd and 3rd dimensions without using structures typedefs etc

**EDIT**
As pointed out by [felix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2371524/felix-palmen) 
what I am looking for is `int (*matrix)[13][13] = (int(*)[13][13])malloc(1000*sizeof(matrix));`

Comment: Don't go OTT with three stars. `int *matrix[13][13]` is a 2D array of pointers to `int`. Is that what you need, or some `int` arrays each size 13x13?

Comment: This question probably provides the best solution if you want a true 3d array:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: I guess you're looking for `int (*matrix)[13][13] = malloc(1000 * sizeof *matrix);`

Comment: or, instead of the `struct`, you could also just use a `typedef`, which would avoid the "messy" declaration of a pointer-to-array. Without the parantheses, it's an array-of-pointers instead.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I dont want to allocate a multi dimensional array. I know how to do that i am curios to know what this variable represents

Comment: @SiddharthChabra Stated. It's an array of array of pointers. (an array of 13 arrays of 13 pointers each). And given what you seem to want, it's useless.

Comment: @FelixPalmen already using a struct, and typdef is similar

Comment: @SiddharthChabra yes, you want to allocate a multi-dimensional array. The code with the `struct` around does basically just this.

Comment: @rcgldr no, as `matrix` is not a **type** in my line. The type of `matrix` is the pointer, so `sizeof(matrix)` would be just the size of a pointer.

Comment: `int *matrix[13][13]` is an [array 13 of array 13 of pointer to int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*matrix%5B13%5D%5B13%5D) - great web-site.

Comment: I wanted to know if the was a way to have a variable with a Dynamic 1st dimention and static 2nd 3rd dimentions in C

Comment: @rcgldr `sizeof(matrix)` is the size of a variable of pointer type. Felix has it right. Optionally, `calloc` also works: `int (*matrix)[13][13] = calloc(1000, sizeof *matrix);`

Comment: @SiddharthChabra which is a multi-dimensional array that you dynamically allocate. Have a look at Andrew's link instead of complaining. I commented the correct line for allocation above.

Comment: @FelixPalmen - deleted my prior comment, I only meant to change `matrix` to `push`.

Comment: Try `struct matrix *array_of_matrices = malloc(sizeof *array_of_matrices * N);`

Comment: @SiddharthChabra "*already using a struct, and typdef is similar*" <- no, it isn't. Not at all. And you should work a little on your attitude.

Comment: @SiddharthChabra The answer to your clarified question is *exactly* what  Felix showed you. There are no typedefs nor structs in that allocation. The superior dimension is dynamic, the rest are static, *exactly* as you requested.

Comment: `How will I use the above mentioned variable?` push[i] or *(push + i) would point to the "ith" 13 by 13 matrix.

Comment: @WhozCraig malloc requires a type cast (atleast in VS) what type cast do I use?

Comment: @SiddharthChabra in standard C it does *not* require a typecast. MS's braindead implementation of the standard will warn, but not fail to compile that line. Bonified C compilers will happily accept it. In standard C you need *not* cast to, or from, `void *` to non-const object pointer types. If you are using MS's compiler, you can either (a) disable that *specific* warning in those specific locations via pragma, (b) use a typedef alias and cast against that, (c) long-hand it and use `(int(*)[13][13])` as the  cast. That MS continues to warn against that has been a frustration for years.

Comment: Your edit is wrong. The "harmless" part is the unnecessary and very ugly cast. The real problem is, your type is still wrong. Also, don't edit an answer into a question. That's what the answers are for. If something is missing (shouldn't be the case here), you can self-answer.

Comment: `int (*matrix)[13][13] = (int(*)[13][13])malloc(1000*sizeof(matrix));` is almost right.  Use `int (*matrix)[13][13] = malloc(sizeof *matrix * 1000);`. Drop the cast and use `*matrix` in the size calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed that sometimes beginner programmers are finding typedef-ing the multidimensional matrices which have to be dynamically allocated easier as it reduces the problem to the single star pointer and the sizeof of the defined type and pointer to it is much easier to understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int my13x13matrix[13][13];

int main(void) {
    my13x13matrix *mylargematrix = malloc(1000 * sizeof(*mylargematrix));

    mylargematrix[999][12][12] = 5;

    printf("%d \n", mylargematrix[999][12][12]);
    return 0;
}
```

you can also use the single star pointer arithmetic.

```
my13x13matrix *anotherpointer = &mylargematrix[10];
(*anotherpointer)[5][5] = 1;
anotherpointer++;
(*anotherpointer)[5][5] = 2;

printf("%d %d\n", mylargematrix[10][5][5], mylargematrix[11][5][5]);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't want to use

```
int *matrix[13][13];
```

That will declare a `[13][13]` array of `int*`s.

You need

```
// pointer to "an array of 13 x 13 ints"
int (*matrix)[13][13];
```

or simplify it by using a type alias.

```
typedef int matrix_type[13][13];
matrix_type* matrix_ptr;
```

You can allocate memory for such a variable using

```
matrix_type* matrix_ptr = malloc(1000*sizeof(*matrix_ptr));
```

and assign values to it using

```
matrix_ptr[0][0][0] = 0;

...

matrix_ptr[999][12][12] = 0;
```

Comment: `using` in C? interesting

Comment: @P__J__, sorry. Got mixed up with the tags.

Comment: and now you repeat my answer :)

Comment: @P__J__ Only partially - this answer shows how to correctly have a pointer to array *without* typedef...

Comment: @P__J__ always write complete and self-contained answers. Comments are considered irrelevant when it comes to answering.

Comment: @FelixPalmen - in my answer I just want to show thy this not very good typedef way may by convenient at some stage of the C learning.

Comment: @P__J__ which makes it a *partial answer*, which is fine as well. But a *complete* answer is always better -- I just wanted to point out that comments don't matter. If they contain part of the answer, repeat it anyways (and, possibly, elaborate on it). I could have written an answer myself, but I was too lazy ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen - repeating the comments is IMO not OK, as person who has commented may write the answer later in more convenient time